# promise in nodejs returns only 2 objects out of 6

Tags: node.js, promise

I have 6 objects linked in an array but in promise after looping though length is 6 it only returns 2 objects
here is my piece of code

```
    router.get('/shopping-cart', isLoggedIn, function (req, res, next) {
    qryFilter = { "_id": req.user._id };
    User.find(qryFilter, function (err, user) {
        console.log(req.user.productId.length);
        var promises = [];
        var productcart = [];
        for(i=0;i<req.user.productId.length;i++)
        {
            promises.push(Promise.resolve(Product.find({ "_id": 
  req.user.productId[i] }).lean().exec().then(function (product) {
                productcart.push(product);  
                console.log(i+"."+product); //the out put is 6.[object Object]   
          })));
        }   
        Promise.all(promises).then(function() { 
        res.render('shop/shopping-cart', {
            layout: 'eshop/blank',
            user: user,
            productcart:productcart,
        });                 
    });
    });
});

the output is 6.[object Object] where it has to be pushing 6 objects i just get 2 on later end
```

Comment: i am so sorry the above codes is perfectly working my fault had deleted the products from db which gave empty objects when those ids were passed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about pushing the promises in the array and use the `Promise.all` result? which be essentially same as `productcart`

```
for (i = 0; i < req.user.productId.length; i++) {
    promises.push(
        Product.find({
            "_id":req.user.productId[i]
        })
    );
}
```

And then do the promise all

```
Promise.all(promises).then(function(products) { 
    //do some operation with products like lean() exec()
    res.render('shop/shopping-cart', {
        layout: 'eshop/blank',
        user: user,
        productcart:products,
    });
});
```

This may work and IMO it's little clearer

Comment: hello aritra thanks for the response even this gives me the same output 4 empty and only 2 objects something like this                                                                                          6
[ Promise { [] },
  Promise { [] },
  Promise { [] },
  Promise { [] },
  Promise { [ [Object] ] },
  Promise { [ [Object] ] } ]

Comment: i am so sorry the above codes are perfectly working both mine and yours my fault had deleted the products from db which gave empty objects